# Format the last element in the array

Tags: javascript

I have an array, its length can be up to 20 elements:

```
[ '0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482;' ]
```

I need to remove the semicolon from the last element in the array.

Here is the result I expect:

```
[ '0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482' ]
```

```
for (const value of Object.values(arrayOfJobs)) {
    console.log(value)
    const arrayLength = value.length - 1;
    value[arrayLength].replace(';', '');
    console.log(value)
}
```

I tried to do it like this, but it still doesn’t remove the semicolon at the end of the array. My problem is that the value is not assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is almost spot on. You just have to consider `value[arrayLength].replace(';', '')` does not actually change the value but returns a new value back. So assign the new value as such

```
...
value[arrayLength] = value[arrayLength].replace(';', '')
...
```

Also you don't need to iterate through all the items as we just want to grab the last one. So here is your solution tweaked.

```js
const arrayOfJobs = [
  '0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482;'
];

arrayOfJobs[arrayOfJobs.length - 1] = arrayOfJobs[arrayOfJobs.length - 1].replace(';', '');

console.log(arrayOfJobs);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could pop the item, slice the string and push the item to the end of the array.

```js
var array = ['0ad39f02478f5;', '309c9e9051482;', 'dd7d5faf07569;', 'ghdg9f02478f5;', '30967uj051482;', 'ad398ixc478f5;', '39c9frtuyr482;']

array.push(array.pop().slice(0, -1));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` to remove the `;`

```js
var a = ['0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482;'
];
if(a.length>0)
a[a.length - 1] = a[a.length - 1].split(';')[0]
console.log(a)
```

using `replace`

```js
var a = ['0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482;'
];
if(a.length>0)
a[a.length - 1] = a[a.length - 1].replace(';','');
console.log(a)
```

Comment: throws an error when `a.length == 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to get a **copy** of the initial array with the last value altered:

```js
const data = [ 
  '0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482;' 
  ];
  
function getFinalArray(arr) {
  return arr.map((x, i) => {
    if (i === arr.length - 1)
      return x.replace(';', '');
    return x;
  });
}

console.log(getFinalArray(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

in a simple way,

```
l[lastIndex] = l[lastIndex].replace('from', 'to')
```

to get last index => `[].length-1`

```js
l = ['0ad39f02478f5;', '309c9e9051482;', 'dd7d5faf07569;', 'ghdg9f02478f5;', '30967uj051482;', 'ad398ixc478f5;', '39c9frtuyr482;']
l[l.length-1] = l[l.length-1].replace(';', '');
console.log('my list', l);
```

Comment: I need to delete the last semicolon, not all

Comment: check my answer @MegaRoks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

```js
var x = [ '0ad39f02478f5;',
  '309c9e9051482;',
  'dd7d5faf07569;',
  'ghdg9f02478f5;',
  '30967uj051482;',
  'ad398ixc478f5;',
  '39c9frtuyr482;' ]

var len = x.length-1
x[len] = x[len].replace(";", "")
console.log(x)
```